# Sharing Images from computer to iphone using USB and Wi-fi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, synchronization, wifimanager

I want to sync images from computer to iPhone device with the help of USB and Wi-Fi.
How can i create SBWifiManager in my app?
Most of app like My Disk do the same thing I want.

Create IP address of device and then use that address in web-browser of computer to connect with app Wi-Fi Manager, both should be connect with same Wi-Fi. Then sync images from computer to my app.

How should I start and what would be good to know before starting?